# Файлы темы с сайта underscores.me

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, вёрстка, cms, интерфейс

Нашел видео [Посадка на Wordpress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5C8MKlbANU). В нем с 1:57 до 2:30 происходит загрузка темы с сайта [Создание тем для Wordpress](https://underscores.me/). Откуда автор знает какой сайт он выбирает с [Создание тем для Wordpress](https://underscores.me/)? На этом сайте не предлагается выбор внешнего вида темы. Откуда сайт underscores.me знает какая верстка натягивается?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну вполне логично что выбор внешнего вида не предлагается, так как суть ролика заключается в том, что автор, как указано в заголовке, делает "натяжку" своей верстки (которую где-то скачал/купил или сверстал сам автор) на скелетон или стратер, как Вам удобнее, с underscores.

Comment: @Simon см. с 0:00 до 4:00. **Откуда** сайт underscores.me **знает** какая верстка натягивается?

Comment: Никто не откуда не знает, почему вообще сайт должен об этом знать?

Comment: @Simon Ну для того чтобы сайт сформировал шаблон сайта на вордпресс, сайт должен знать какая верстка натягивается. Если эти данные не задаются, то непонятно какое название вводится на underscores.me и какой шаблон выдается. Если смотреть видео, то получается, что автор ввел некоторое название шаблона сайта (непонятно откуда он берет верстку) и получает некий шаблон сайта (откуда берутя данные для него).

Comment: Ну вот, разработчик сам, своими ручками переносит верстку в необходимые шаблоны, подключает необходимые стили, скрипты в стартер тему и так далее. Вы видео вообще смотрели или просто тайм-коды кидаете? Стартовая тема -- это просто основа с рядом базовых функций и файлов для вашей новой пользовательской темы, грубо говоря.

Comment: @questionsandanswers Да название вообще на свое усмотрение можете ввести, что за бред? Каким образом внешний вид от названия зависит? Вы путаете создание темы с использованием уже готовой.

Comment: @Simon Откуда пользователь знает, что по названию верстки формируется нужный внешний вид?

Comment: @questionsandanswers название не генерирует внешний вид. Он сам придумал название. Название верстки не имеет отношения к внешнеми виду, Вы вообще читаете что я пишу Вам? Автор создает свою собственную тему используя верстку которую он сам или скачал или купил. И из этой верстки создает свою тему. То что он скачивает с сайта underscores имеет очень базовый внешний вид, не имеющий отношения к конечному результату.

Comment: @Simon вы не смотрели видео.

Comment: @questionsandanswers на таймкоде [2:28](https://youtu.be/Q5C8MKlbANU?t=149) он Вам показывает как выглядит то что он скачал с underscores.me и говорит: "Как Вы видите, это ЧИСТАЯ тема"

Comment: @Simon а как underscores.me по названию Verstach генерирует верстку (указанную на 2:28)?

Comment: @questionsandanswers она всегда одинаковая, вне зависимости от названия, там только базовые стили, можете сами проверить, сгенерировав 10 тем с разными названия, скачав их и активировав по очереди.

Answer (score 1):

underscores.me и не нужно знать о вашей верстке, это тема стандартная, "голая" для модификаций и внедрения верстки. Скажем так это чертеж, основа (скелет) для создание wp сайта